# How to track anonomous SMS on your smartphone

Tags: spoofing

I sometimes receive sms from unknown numbers asking me to send money on another unknown number.

Is there a way to track the source of such numbers through logs or other technologies or solutions?

Comment: There is no need to shout - I've changed your title from being all-uppercase. Also, while there is a likely a way to get back to the original sender by analyzing logs, these are no logs the end-user has access to, i.e. they are logs at the mobile provider.

Answer (score 2):

**Contact your mobile network**

The best solution is to contact your mobile network. They can track the sender and help you.

> I sometimes receive sms from unknown numbers asking me to send money
>   on another unknown number.

This sounds like a scam and your mobile network operator or carrier can block the senders for you if requested.

Comment: Actually, I've been there - done that, I second that. Contacting your provider asap it's the best solution.